# Что значат квадратные скобки вокруг названия переменных в JS?

Tags: javascript

Уже год изучаю JavaScript и не могу понять, зачем, как, и почему при создании переменной, ее можно обогнуть в **квадратные скобки**. Только начал изучать структуры данных и алгоритмы. Вижу не первый раз, до сих пор не понимаю значение:

```
const [curr, result] = st.pop();
```

Буду очень признателен, если поможете разобраться.

Comment: Деструктивное присваивание

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Деструктурирующее присваивание – это специальный синтаксис, который позволяет нам «распаковать» массивы или объекты в кучу переменных, так как иногда они более удобны. Деструктуризация также прекрасно работает со сложными функциями, которые имеют много параметров, значений по умолчанию и так далее.

```js
// у нас есть массив с именем и фамилией
let arr = ["Ilya", "Kantor"]

// деструктурирующее присваивание
// записывает firstName=arr[0], surname=arr[1]
let [firstName, surname] = arr;

console.log(firstName); // Ilya
console.log(surname); // Kantor
```

[***Источник***](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment)