# можете объяснить как это работает (a, b) = (b, a);

Tags: c#

```
int a = 10; 
int b = 15;

Console.WriteLine($"{a}-{b}");

(a, b) = (b, a); // обмен

Console.WriteLine($"{a}-{b}");
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: Правое выражение вычисляется полностью, кортеж с вычисленными значениями распаковывается поэлементно в левый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно понять что такое Tuple (a, b) - кортежи и их [деконструкция](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct).

Кортежи

> Кортежи, доступные в C# 7.0 и более поздних версиях, предоставляют краткий
> синтаксис для группирования нескольких элементов данных в упрощенную
> структуру данных.

```
(double, int) t1 = (4.5, 3);
Console.WriteLine($"Tuple with elements {t1.Item1} and {t1.Item2}.");
// Output:
// Tuple with elements 4.5 and 3.

(double Sum, int Count) t2 = (4.5, 3);
Console.WriteLine($"Sum of {t2.Count} elements is {t2.Sum}.");
// Output:
// Sum of 3 elements is 4.5.
```

Деконструкции кортежей

> Язык C# имеет встроенную поддержку деконструкции кортежей, которая
> позволяет извлекать из кортежа все элементы за одну операцию. Общий
> синтаксис деконструкции кортежа напоминает синтаксис его определения:
> переменные, которым будут присвоены элементы кортежа, указываются в
> круглых скобках в левой части оператора присваивания. Например,
> следующий оператор присваивает элементы кортежа из четырех элементов
> четырем отдельным переменным:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var (address, city, zip) = QueryCityData();
    }

    private static (string, int, double) QueryCityData(string name)
    {
        if (name == "New York City")
            return (name, 8175133, 468.48);

        return ("", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

в Вашем примере сначала конструируется кортеж и тут же деконструируется на присваивании и получается обмен.

```
(a, b) = (b, a); // обмен
```

Подобный синтаксис есть и в JavaScript с объектами и [массивами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181236/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-js/1181237#1181237).