# Практическое применение Deconstruct

Tags: c#

Недавно сел читать книгу `C# 7.0 in a Nutshell`. И нашел нововведение в `C# 7.0` которое прошло мимо меня стороной - "Деконструкторы" (не путайте с деструкторами и финализаторами).

Естественно я побрел на родной и любимый [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) и начал читать о том что мне может дать данная конструкция. В статье описаны только синтетические (далекие от реальности) примеры. Деконструкторов может быть объявлено в классе от 1 до N. Можно игнорировать (`out _`) "ненужные" в данный момент поля. Но какое применение можно этому найти? Это синтаксический сахар!

Катаюсь головой об клавиатуру и не могу придумать применение. Может быть Вы уже сталкивались и применяли? На `github` не смог ничего найти - [github](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&p=1&q=Deconstruct&type=Code).

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1183825/373567), совсем свежее.

Comment: @aepot с кортежами я прекрасно понимаю. это даже естественно и круто, на самом деле я использовал и использую деконструирование кортежей, сам не зная как правильно оно называется. Меня интересует именно работа деконструирования с типами пользователей. Это не естественно видеть var (p1,p2,p3) = userObject;

Comment: `Это синтаксический сахар!` почти все уникальные фишки языка являются синтаксическим сахаром :)

Comment: Кратко можно описать так: _конструктор_ позволяет создать объект _одной_ строкой. _Деконструктор_ позволяет разобрать объект _одной_ строкой. Без конструктора пришлось бы задавать свойства объекта _многими_ строками кода. Без деконструктора приходится получать данные из свойств объекта _многими_ строками.

Comment: Уже начали минусовать... Я скажу более подробно : мне кажется серьезным когда в пользовательские типы вводятся нововведения. Да мы не переопределяем метод деструконструктора, как это делаем с методами типа object, мы можем делать деконструкторов от 1 до N и деконструктор позволяет позволяет оперировать надо результатом как с кортежем - результат и является кортежем. Впредь я буду задавать более ясные вопросы. Прошу прощения если кого нибудь обидел.

Comment: Раньше видел тут вопросы, по типу "А зачем нужны интерфейсы?", где человеку всячески пытались объяснить их суть, но он не понимал, просто в голове не укладывалась вся идеология и польза их применения. Я, читая подобные вопросы понял одно - если не понятно и не знаете, как применять, то это означает, что оно вам сейчас не нужно. Просто знайте, что такая возможность существует, а когда она вам понадобится, вот тогда вы поймете всю суть деконструкции и сразу найдете применение. А на данный момент, на ваш вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ, и я проголосую за закрытие.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906305/c-sharp-7-0-deconstructor похожая тема с EnSO. некоторые люди тоже разделяют мой скептецизм. на вопрос человеку ответили кратко и содержательно - в рамках пользовательского типа. никто не копировал статью с msdn. закройте пожалуйста этот вопрос.

Comment: @PeterLavreniuk, в отличие от вопроса на enso, в котором спрашивалось - действительно ли это просто синтаксический сахар, и на который ответили - да, это синтаксический сахар. Плюс те же самые примеры, как именно реализован деконструктор. В твоем вопросе, сразу утверждается, что это синтаксический сахар. Поэтому, не совсем ясно, что еще ты хочешь увидеть в ответе. Примеры использования предоставлены на странице msdn. Поиск на github не увенчался успехом, так как данная синтаксическая конструкция, как правило, не подписывается как `Deconstruct`.