# Как устроен Object.entries?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, как работает код ниже.

Каким образом идет сравнение зарплат, а затем как возвращается наибольшая зарплата?

Мы же просто копируем значения объекта в две переменные?

Как копированные данные из объекта в две переменные
помогают посчитать наибольшую зарплату?

По идее **Object.entries** должен возвращать пары **ключ/значение, а не одно значение.**

Объясните пожалуйста, может я чего-то не понимаю.

```js
let salaries = {
  "John": 100,
  "Pete": 300,
  "Mary": 250
};


function topSalary(salaries) {
  let max = 0;
  let maxName = null;

  for(const [name, salary] of Object.entries(salaries)) {
    if (max < salary) {       
      max = salary;           // Копировать все значения объекта в переменную max?
      maxName = salary;       // Копировать все значения в переменную maxName?
    }
  }
  return maxName;             // Вернуть переменную с копированными данными из объекта?
}

alert(topSalary(salaries));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, вам тут просто нужно понять, как меняется значение max. Запустите у себя цикл, только в несколько упрощенном виде:

```
let salaries = {
  "John": 100,
  "Pete": 300,
  "Mary": 250
};
// Во-первых посмтрите, что делает с объектом Object.entries
console.log(Object.entries(salaries))


let max = 0;

  for(const [name, salary] of Object.entries(salaries)) {
   console.log("Значание max до условия if: " + max)
    if (max < salary) {       
      max = salary;           // Копировать все значения объекта в переменную max?
      
    } 
    console.log("Значание max после условия If: " + max,
    "Значание salary сейчас: " + salary)
  }
```

Значание max до входа в цикл - 0. Ок, потом, в цикле перебираются значения в сэлэрис. Если значение salary больше того, что сейчас находится в max, значит в max нужно записать новое значение. И всё.

Comment: А как цикл выставляет наибольшее число? Что происходит?

Comment: Да просто меняется переменная max. Сначала она 0, после первого прохода, она становится уже 100. А почему? А потому что if (0 < 100) {       
      max = 100;    
И так до тех пор, пока не закончится цикл.
Почитайте как работает деструктурирующее присваивание.
Участник выше дал ссылку

Comment: Но последнее значение у меня не 300, а 250. Тогда должно выводить 250, а не 300. Cудя по вашему комментарию.

Comment: нет. У вас на этот момент в if будет false, потомк что 
```
if (300<250) {       
      max = salary;  а если false то в тело цикла не входим
```

Comment: Значит сработает предыдущий цикл, где в if 300 не меньше(<) 300, а значит присвоить переменной max значение 300? Верно?

Comment: 1) max = 0, salary = 100; записать в max =100,
2) max = 100, salary = 300; записать в max =300, 
3) max = 300, salary = 250; оставить в max =300, потому что 300 больше чем 250
перебор закончен, max = 300

Я же вам всё обложил консоль логами :) Запустит код, посмотрите

Comment: Благодарю вас, теперь я все понял. Из вас вышел бы хороший учитель =)

Answer (score 2):

Тут всё просто

[Object.entries(salaries)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) - метод возвращает массив собственных перечисляемых свойств указанного объекта в формате [key, value]. (То есть массив массивов)

Далее в цикле перебирается внешний массив

```
for(const [name, salary] of Object.entries(salaries)) {
    
}
```

[деструктурирующим присваиванием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181236/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-js/1181237#1181237) значения из внутреннего массива [key, value] присваиваются
[name, salary]. И дабы просто не перебирать внешний массив идет проверка на наибольшее значение

```
if (max < salary) {       
  max = salary;           // Копировать все значения объекта в переменную max?
  maxName = salary;       // Копировать все значения в переменную maxName?
}
```

**PS.** Конечно ваш код будет правильно работать при положительных значениях зарплат

Comment: Где именно идет проверка на наибольшее значение?

Comment: if (max < salary)

Comment: А где внешний массив? У меня тут объект, а не массив.

Comment: Object.entries(salaries)  возращяет массив

Comment: массив из [key, value] - который тоже массив из 2 элементов

Comment: Спасибо, но я все еще не могу понять, как идет сравнение наибольшей зарплаты. Я тут вижу только две переменные с копированными значениями из объекта.

Comment: if (max < salary) - если max - значение которое мы имеем меньше чем salary - тукушее значение итерации цикла. тогда ....

Comment: Что такое про100?

Comment: И где можно прочитать про "И дабы про100 не перебирать внешний массив идет проверка на наибольшее значение"

Comment: Это обычный цикл. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Но там не написано, что "про100 не перебирать внешний массив идет проверка на наибольшее значение"
Если бы был метод, который бы выводил наибольшее число типа Math.max(), то я бы еще понял. Но в этом коде нет аналогичных методов. Тут просто две переменные и все. Я определенно не понимаю чего-то.

Comment: А что по вашему делает  Math.max(). Также сравнивает и возрашяет значение. Тут тоже самое только через проверки

Comment: Где можно прочитать про эти самые проверки в циклах? Ссылку которую вы дали, там ничего не сказано про эти самые проверки при помощи циклов.

Comment: Это комбинация цикла и условия. Получается ципл с условием

Comment: А как цикл выбирает наибольшее число? Как называется это правило или этот термин?

Comment: Обычное условие и занесение нового значения в переменную в случае выполнения условия

Comment: Спасибо за ваше старание, но я все равно не понимаю, каким образом цикл выбирает наибольшее число из всех.

Comment: Цикл не выбирает. Он перебирает значения. А условный оператор проверяет условие и изменяет значение в случае удовлетворения условия